# Is an iphone 5c still enough to publish an ios application?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I need to create an application for IOS.

I know that I need a mac "pc" and an iPhone in order to publish my application.

I am a bit confused. I read somewhere that I need my app to be compiled for IOS 12.x but my phone, iphone 5c (not s) doesn't support such a release.

Will I still be able to publish my app?

Comment: You can add backward app compatibility (below iOS 12.X). I meant by the minimum iOS version support.

Comment: Thanks dahiya, but will they let me publish the application even if I have done my tests using older iOS version?

Comment: Yes you can do, for newer version you can use simulators.

Comment: You absolutely don't need to own an iPhone in order to publish to App Store.

Comment: Desdenova, I published one I think 8 years ago and I had to own an iPhone. If that is the case, thats perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an iPhone to publish apps to App Store. Simply select "Generic iOS Device" under "Build only devices" from the device list then Archive, and then publish to app store.